# Redux action returns undefined?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

Redux store get undefined in action.data, even though my reducer function gets the correct result from the api, my dispatch is in the correct place.

> My Reducer function:

```
const convertPosition = StateHelper.createAsyncOperation(MODULE, 'convertPosition');

export function $convertPosition(lat, long) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(Activity.$processing(MODULE, $convertPosition.name));
    dispatch(convertPosition.request());

    return fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/shared/maps/address?latlong=${lat},${long}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthService.getAccessToken()}`,
      },
    })
      .then(FetchHelper.ResponseHandler, FetchHelper.ErrorHandler)
      .then((result) => dispatch(convertPosition.success(result)))
      .catch((error) => dispatch(convertPosition.failure(error)))
      .finally(() => dispatch(Activity.$done(MODULE, $convertPosition.name)));
  };
}
```

> My Reducer statement:

```
    case convertPosition.SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        locationName: action.data,
      };
    case convertPosition.FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        locationName: null,
      };
```

Comment: Are you sure is `action.data`? normally it's `action.payload` in Redux

Answer (score 0):

After I checked the API with postman, the result was an array so the code was:

```
  ...
  .then((result) => dispatch(convertPosition.success({result: result})))
  ....
```